# Trying to create a simple Multiple Choice game

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml, getelementbyid, radio-group

My function that lists the question and choices won't work. I keep getting the error code `document.getElementById(...)` is null or not an object. The syntax appears to be correct.

I want the questions and choices to appear in the same divs. I do not want to list all my questions at once. When the user completes a question, they then move on to the next question which will appear in exactly the same divs as the first question until all the questions have been seen.

```
<script>

var questions = new Array();
questions[0] = 'Is there a difference between a jungle and a rain forest?'
questions[1] = 'What is the world\'s most common religion?',
questions[2] = 'What is the second largest country (in size) in the world?';

var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = ['No difference', 'Some difference', 'Completely different'],
choices[1] = ['Christianity', 'Buddhism', 'Hinduism', 'Islam'],
choices[2] = ['USA', 'China', 'Canada', 'Russia'];

var answers = new Array();
answers[0] = ['Some difference'],
answers[1] = ['Christianity'],
answers[2] = ['Canada'];

var score = 0;
i= 0;

var listQuestion = function(){  
    if( i < questions.length ){
        document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML = '<p>'+questions[i]+'</p>';
        for (k=0; k<choices[i].length; k++){
            document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML ='<p><input type = "radio" name = "questionchoice">'+choices[i][k]+'</p>';
        }
        document.getElementById("myDiv3").innerHTML = '<p><button onClick = "getRadioValue()">Check</button></p> <br>';
    };
};

var getRadioValue = function(){
    for ( var h = 0; h < document.getElementsByName('questionchoice').length; h++ ){
        var value = '';
        if (document.getElementsByName('questionchoice')[h].checked==true){
            value = document.getElementsByName('questionchoice')[h].value;
            score+=1
        }
    }
    if (value== answers[i]){
        document.getElementById("myDiv4").innerHTML ="That is correct. </br><button input type = 'submit' onClick = 'loadContent()'> Next Question</button>";   
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv4").innerHTML ="That is incorrect. </br><button input type = 'submit' onClick = 'loadContent()'> Next Question</button>"; 
    }
    i++;
};

var whatIsScore = function(){
    return score; 
}

window.onload = listQuestion();

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv1"></div> 
    <div id="myDiv2"></div>
    <div id="myDiv3"></div>
    <div id="myDiv4"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML to go with that? You should have at least four `<div>` elements on the page somewhere with id values; myDiv1, myDiv2, myDiv3, myDiv4.

Comment: Hi Dave, I do. See below.


<body>
<div id="myDiv1"></div> 
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
<div id="myDiv3"></div>
<div id="myDiv4"></div>


</body>

Comment: can you add your full source to the question so we can recreate your error. It can't find your element and you're trying to access the innerHTML property of a null object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var questions = new Array();
questions[0] = 'Is there a difference between a jungle and a rain forest?';
questions[1] = 'What is the world\'s most common religion?',
questions[2] = 'What is the second largest country (in size) in the world?';

var choices = new Array();
choices[0] = ['No difference', 'Some difference', 'Completely different'],
choices[1] = ['Christianity', 'Buddhism', 'Hinduism', 'Islam'],
choices[2] = ['USA', 'China', 'Canada', 'Russia'];

var answers = new Array();
answers[0] = ['Some difference'],
answers[1] = ['Christianity'],
answers[2] = ['Canada'];

var score = 0;
i= 0;

var listQuestion = function(){  
    if(i<questions.length){
        document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML = '<p>'+questions[i]+'</p>';
        var choicesOutput=[];//new Array()
        for (var k=0; k<choices[i].length; k++){
            choicesOutput.push(
                '<p><input type = "radio" name ='
                +' "questionchoice">'+choices[i][k]+'</p>');
        }
        document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML =choicesOutput.join("");
        document.getElementById("myDiv3").innerHTML = 
            '<p><button onClick = "getRadioValue()">Check</button></p> <br>';
    }
};
var getRadioValue = function(){
    var value = '';
    for (var h = 0; 
        h < document.getElementsByName('questionchoice').length; h++){
        if (document.getElementsByName('questionchoice')[h]
            .checked==true){
            value = document.getElementsByName('questionchoice')[h].value;
            score++;
        }
    }
    if (value== answers[i]){
        document.getElementById("myDiv4").innerHTML =
            "That is correct. </br><button input type = "
            +"'submit' onClick = 'loadContent()'> Next Question</button>";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("myDiv4").innerHTML ="That is incorrect. "
           +"</br><button input type = 'submit' onClick = 'loadContent()'> N"
           +"ext Question</button>"; 
    }
    i++;
};
var whatIsScore = function(){
    return score; 
};
function loadContent(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv4").innerHTML="";
    listQuestion();
}
window.onload = listQuestion;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv1"></div> 
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
<div id="myDiv3"></div>
<div id="myDiv4"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still getting this error 

Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: if you post the complete page I can check it out for you. If the error is triggered on the line trying to get myDiv3 by it's id and that element doesn't exist or doesn't have the id (case sensitive) than you'll get such an error. I see that I used the wrong ID for the answers, I used myDiv3 instead of myDiv2. will correct it

Comment: Hi HMR, I've posted all the code above. When I used your code, I got the same error message (listed above), so I decided to post my original code. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, any luck with this? I'm stumped.

Comment: window.onload=listQuestion() should be: window.onload=listQuestion.